# Upgrading Aspnet Core application on linux gives Error

Tags: linux, asp.net-core, debian

I am trying to upgrade an Asp.net core application on Debian vm. After I copy the new dlls and test with dotnet path-to-my-app.dll I get this error.

```
LTTng-UST: Error (-17) while registering tracepoint probe. Duplicate registration of tracepoint probes having the same name is not allowed.
```

Two further clarify, I am upgrading a self contained app. I first stop the running service and then replace the files with new ones and then just do a 
`dotnet path-to-myapp.dll`
and the above error appears. There was no change in appsettings or any other configuration changes. Do I need to stop any other services as well?

Answer (score 0):

For the general public here is the issue and the solution:
The version on my linux VM was 2.1.5 and my App target version was 2.1.0, However the previous target framework version of installed app was 2.1.0 and it was working fine. I only made a few changes and went on to deploy the new version, first it failed to build with the command "dotnet build --runtime linux-x64" complaining about different frameworks to restore and build. So I first changed the project file to use

`<TargetLatestRuntimePatch>true</TargetLatestRuntimePatch>`
And after that it failed to run with the above error. Finally I changed the `RuntimeFrameworkVersion` to 2.1.5 to match my host version AND didn't use the "dotnet build --runtime linux-x64" command but Publish instead. I also read about using the Publish command here:

https://codeblog.dotsandbrackets.com/package-downgrade-issue/